# Address to show directly pedestrian, cycling or car itinerary in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my program, I build the address of the itinerary I want to show with GM :

"http://maps.google.fr/maps?lang=fr&saddr="+add_from+"&daddr="+add_to;

After, if user wants to show cycling or pedestrian way, he can click on the corresponding button in the page

However, I'd like to show directly the cycling or pedestrian way. Is that an argument I can pass after the  "?"  of  the address to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If that can help you, I finded solution, you must add "dirflg" parameter

"http://maps.google.fr/maps?lang=fr&saddr="+add_from+"&daddr="+add_to&dirflg=b" for cycling

"http://maps.google.fr/maps?lang=fr&saddr="+add_from+"&daddr="+add_to&dirflg=w" for pedestrian

without parameters (default) for car

Trachy